# Update the table after calculating the amount based on multiple records from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one is Base_table and another one is Txn_table as follows

### Base_table

```
Person  | Amount
----------------
P1        300
p2        200   
p3        100
```

### Txn_table

```
Person  |  txn_type  |  Amount
---------------------------------
P1        Debit         200    
P2        Credit        200    
P3        Debit         100    
P1        Credit        400
```

I need to update **Base_Table** based on **Txn_table** data like P1 has done Debit and Credit ,the total calculation is something like (Credit-Debit) = (400-200) = 200,and already P1 is having 300 in **Base_table** so total 300 + 200 = 500 value needs to be updated in **Base_Table** for P1.in the same way for others as well please help me to write the **Oracle SQL** query

And the data should be like this in Base_table  after updation.

### Base_table

```
Person  | Amount    
P1        500    
p2        400    
p3        0
```

**Note:** here I should  not go for PLsql Block only i need to perform this updation using SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

An inline correlated subquery might get the job done:

```
UPDATE base_table b
SET b.amount =
    b.amount 
    + NVL(
        (SELECT SUM(DECODE(t.txn_type, 'Credit', 1, -1) * t.amount)
        FROM txn_table t
        WHERE t.person = b.person
    ), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a typical way to update one table from another is to use correlated subqueries:

```
update base_table b
    set amount = b.amount +
                 (select sum(case when t.txn_type = 'Credit' then t.amount else - t.amount end)
                  from txn_table t
                  where t.person = b.person
                 )
    where exists (select 1
                  from txn_table t
                  where t.person = b.person
                  having sum(case when t.txn_type = 'Credit' then t.amount else - t.amount end) <> 0
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to suggest an other approach.

```
merge into base_table tt
    using
    ( select person , sum( decode(upper(txn_type) ,
                               'CREDIT', + AMOUNT ,
                               'DEBIT', - AMOUNT
                             ) ) as final
                            from Txn_table
                  group by person  ) b
    on ( tt.person = b.person )
    when matched then
    update  set tt.AMOUNT =  tt.AMOUNT + b.final
```